# how to replace the localhost with its actual path?

Tags: asp.net, response

I use following code to open a file. When I was prompt to open/save the file, it showed the file was from localhost, but the file could be in a network drive. Is there any way I chould replace the localhost with its actual location?

```
byte[] bts = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "Application/octect-stream");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bts.Length.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ((LinkButton)sender).Text);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bts);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

Edit: ((LinkButton)sender).Text) is the filename without path. The actual location of the file is, for example, Y:\SPR_Upload, and Y is a network drive that is mapped to C$(\m6300-7). When I clicked the file, I was prompted Do you want to open or save XXX(24.1KB) from localhost? I want to replace the localhost with m6300-7. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you're using

```
((LinkButton)sender).Text
```

to get the filename. If the LinkButton that's calling this has `localhost` hard-coded into its Text value, you'll have to correct it there.

If you've hard-coded the Text property of your LinkButton to something like `http://localhost:0000/....`, you'll need to correct that. With near-zero exceptions, all links in your application should be relative, such as `/home/index` or `/support/default.aspx`.

Note that the `Content-Disposition` header just sets the filename that the browser uses or presents to the user - it can be set to anything, and doesn't have to reference a real file on the server.

As such, if you just want the filename (stripping all path information, etc), you can use

```
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(((LinkButton)Sender).Text);
```

then use the resulting value in your `Content-Disposition` header assignment.

**Update**

When the browser says "Would you like to download xxxx.xx from localhost?", it gets the server name (localhost in this case) from the URL that is used to download the file. If you run the same app on, say, "www.mysite.com", the browser will say "Would you like to download xxxx.xx from www.mysite.com?" For security reasons, etc, you shouldn't be able to override the name of the server used in that prompt.

The `Content-Disposition` header just sets the filename that the browser shows the user.

Comment: Thanks. I got the idea. Guess you are not allowed to change it.

Comment: A better question might be, why do you want to change the identity of the server that's presented to the user?